# The law of identity: two interpretations

Tags: logic

Some philosophers state the law of identity as "if p, then p" or "p iff p" (i.e. in propositional logic). On the other hand, others state it in a completely different language, for example: "A is A".

What are the origins of these two styles?

Comment: Do these ways of articulating identity strike you as different on a deeper level than wording? (I'm trying to better understand your concern about "the origin of these two styles")

Comment: At least, "p iff p" contains two propositions, but "A is A" contains only one... ?

Comment: Hello. Could you provide a specific reference to a philosopher that regards "if p, then p" as the law of identity?

Comment: You do realise though, that "if p then p" is not equivalent with "p iff p"? The first is implication, the second equivalence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A is A** is the "traditional" form of the [Law of identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_identity) dating from the medieval commentators to [Aristotle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_thought#Aristotle).

[Aristotle' logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/) is a logic of [terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_logic); terms are (roughly speaking) "names" for objects : individuals, etc.

Thus, the *identity* is a relation between names or objects, and thus it is expressed with "is" (in formal logic : "=", and the usual law : **x=x**).

*Propositional logic* is formulated in terms of *sentential* variables, standing for sentences: thus, the relations between them are expressed with the connectives : "and, or, not, if__ then___".

"If **p**, then **p**" is one of the most elementary law of propositional calculus (in many textbook it is the first one derived).

In Alfred North Whitehead & Bertrand Russell, [Principia Mathematica to *56](https://books.google.it/books?id=_v4LBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA99) (2nd ed - 1927), page 99, we have the law :

> *2.08.  **⊢p ⊃ p**

i.e. any proposition implies itself. This is called the "principle of identity". It is not the same as the "law of identity" ("x is identical with x") [...].

I presume that this is the origin of the modern usage in logic.

Comment: But why we have call it a law/principle? I mean couldn't we derive it from the law of excluded middle and law of non-contradiction?

Comment: @adosar - the form **x=x** is not a propositional formula. This it cannot be derived. The propositional form **p ⊃ p** is derived (as in *Principia* above) from propositional axioms, as well as LEM and LNC.